# A compilation problems in VS2015

Tags: c++, casting, x86, mov, sign-extension

```
   127:    int a = 2815;
00007FF78B5126EE  mov dword ptr [a],0AFFh
   128:
   129:    short c = static_cast<char>(a);
00007FF78B5126F5  movsx    ax,byte ptr [a]
00007FF78B5126FA  mov      word ptr [c],ax
```

In my environment an `int` takes 4 byte and a short takes 2, so in the `movsx` instruction, why there is a byte not a word? Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` is one byte. The `static_cast` casts `a` to a `char`. One byte. Hence, the one-byte value of the `char`-cast variable `a` is moved into `ax`.

Answer (score 0):

It moves the lowest byte of the int `a`, because that's what `static_cast<char>` gives you.